# I want to Delete row of Pandas DataFrame which matches a string and maintain the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named **last_modified_tracking_df**, which has columns as --> Source file,Last_modified_date and Target_folder.

I have a dictionary **last_modified_file_date_dict** which has  type filenames in keys. I want to remove the rows from last_modified_tracking_df which files don't exist in last_modified_tracking_df.

I have written the below code for that-->

```
    for log_path in last_modified_tracking_df['Source file']:
                if log_path not in last_modified_file_date_dict.keys():
                    last_modified_tracking_df = last_modified_tracking_df[last_modified_tracking_df['Source file'].ne(log_path)]
print(last_modified_tracking_df)
```

This code is removing the required rows but output is coming as

```
0   C:\test\file1...  2021-07-05T10:38:58   target1
1   C:\test\file2...  2021-10-20T09:18:43   target2
3   C:\test\file4...  2021-10-21T04:54:37   target4
4   C:\test\file5...  2021-10-18T13:28:16   target5
```

In the above output the index is getting skipped for deleted row. My question is **"is there any better efficient approach to do this?"** and **"how can I get consecutive indexes even after removing the rows?"** Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could get rid of the loop entirely, and use `isin` instead of `ne`

So assuming you have

```
>>> last_modified_tracking_df
     source_file   last_modified_date target_folder
0  C:\test\file1  2021-07-05T10:38:58       target1
1  C:\test\file2  2021-10-20T09:18:43       target2
2  C:\test\file3  2021-10-18T13:28:16       target3
3  C:\test\file4  2021-10-21T04:54:37       target4
4  C:\test\file5  2021-10-18T13:28:16       target5
5  C:\test\file6  2021-10-18T13:28:16       target6
```

And

```
>>> last_modified_file_date_dict
{'C:\\test\\file1': '2021-07-05T10:38:58',
 'C:\\test\\file3': '2021-10-21T04:54:37'}
```

Just call

```
last_modified_tracking_df = last_modified_tracking_df[
    last_modified_tracking_df["source_file"].isin(last_modified_file_date_dict.keys())
].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result

```
>>> last_modified_tracking_df
     source_file   last_modified_date target_folder
0  C:\test\file1  2021-07-05T10:38:58       target1
1  C:\test\file3  2021-10-18T13:28:16       target3
```

Comment: if I want to check and save the negation, instead of isin which method can I use?

Comment: You can just negate an entire expression with the `~` symbol so 
`~last_modified_tracking_df["source_file"].isin(last_modified_file_date_dict.keys())`

Answer (score 2):

Using `DataFrame.reset_index(drop=True)` works, and assuming you don't want to reassign the dataframe to a new variable, you'd also want `inplace=True`

```
last_modified_tracking_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Otherwise if you'd want to reassign, you'd go for

```
new_df = last_modified_tracking_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This resets and gives each row a consecutive index value in respect to the previous row's index value.

As for checking the row's values, you'd probably want to iterate through the rows (`DataFrame.iterrows()`) and delete/drop just the single row, not create a new dataframe without said row:

```
for index, row in last_modified_tracking_df.iterrows():
    if row["Source file"] not in last_modified_file_date_dict.keys():
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. And can you please help me with any better approach for the checking? In my code I have re-assign the last_modified_tracking_df everytime it delete a row.

Comment: @Gorib_coder I added a better solution to row value checking and deleting if necessary (at least what I think should be better).